# swing - JLabel in GridBagLayout with long text

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to design a popup to notify receiving a new e-mail.
This is the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author luca
 */
public class Popup extends JDialog {


    public Popup() {
        super.setSize(260, 100);

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);


        JLabel header = new JLabel("Hai ricevuto una nuova email");
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        add(header, gbc);

        JLabel mittente = new JLabel("luca.cillario@yahoo.it");
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        add(mittente, gbc);

        JLabel argomento = new JLabel("info voto esame");
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        add(argomento, gbc);

        JLabel icona = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img/email.png"));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(icona, gbc);


        this.setLocation(400, 400);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
        mittente.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(180, 16));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Popup();
    }

}
```

When the text in the labels isn't too long everything works fine, i get something like this:
[image]

But when the text is too long, this is what i get:
[image]

Is there a way of getting something like this?
[image]

I found other questions about this thing and i tried to work on label.setMaximumSize(), i tried to write text with html tags...But nothing worked out. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case it helps to set the `weightx` of the image to 1, while everything else gets a 0. There are also various other changes. Inspect the code closely for the changes.

I would also recommend setting the full text as the tool tip for each label. If the user wants to see the entire details, they just need to point the mouse at the label.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Popup extends JDialog {

    public Popup() {
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        JLabel header = new JLabel("Hai ricevuto una nuova email");
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        add(header, gbc);

        gbc.weightx = 0;
        JLabel mittente = new JLabel("luca.cillario@yahoo.itabcditabcditabcditabcditabcd");
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        add(mittente, gbc);

        JLabel argomento = new JLabel("info voto esame");
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        add(argomento, gbc);

        JLabel icona = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
                new BufferedImage(40,60,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(icona, gbc);

        this.setLocation(400, 400);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        pack();
        super.setSize(260, 100);
        this.setVisible(true);
        mittente.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(180, 16));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Popup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that's exactly what I was looking for!